# How is less implemented for std::type_index?

Tags: c++, c++14

`std::type_index` has a less than operator which is supposed to use `std::type_info` but `std::type_info` has not a less than operator.

So how can `std::type_index` have a less than operator ?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index/operator_cmp) states:

> Compares the underlying std::type_info objects as defined by an
>   implementation-defined ordering. The comparison is done by
>   [type_info::before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/before).

Answer (score 3):

You see a explanation in the article about the comparison operators [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index/operator_cmp). tl;dr: `std::type_info` has a member function `before` that is used and has an implementation defined ordering between types.